# 2 parameters for event handlers?

Tags: actionscript-3, parameters, event-handling, helper

`

```
public class names extends MovieClip
{
   public function names(YourName:String)
    {
      this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,doThis);
    }
    public function doThis(e:event,Name:String)
    {
      trace(Name);
    }
}
```

Im trying to pass the value "YourName" form the consturctor to the doThis class. I dono if im just really stupid or not but i cant understand how to do it. is there a way i can have 2 parameters for the doThis class?? or is there another solution

`

Comment: although you could make a workaround where you pass both arguments to the function, @Jari 's answer is what you would usually do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may help you:

```
package {

public class Names extends MovieClip
{
   private var name:String ;

   public function Names(name:String)
    {
      this.name = name ;
      this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, doThis);
    }

    public function doThis(event:Event):void
    {
      trace(this.name);
    }
}
}
```

All functions, that are called after events being dispatched accept only 1 parameter:`Event`.

All you do is just use `instance variables`. Good luck, hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks a lot! :) i cant believe i could not for the life of me figure that out -.-.

Comment: You're welcome :) AS3 is an awesome language, you are on the right direction.